# How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-tweak

I have heard a lot about Ubuntu-Tweak and how it is great for power users, but I don't know how to install it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[image: Home screen]
*The Ubuntu-Tweak Home screen*

---

### Instructions:

Installing Ubuntu-Tweak is rather simple and easy. Follow these simple steps, and you will have Ubuntu-Tweak installed, and be on your way to tweaking Ubuntu to your liking.

### For 12.10 and Earlier:

#### Steps:

1. Add the **PPA**:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`

   - [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
   - [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)
2. Update your sources. (Steps are listed below. **Chose the method that fits your scenario**):

   **Ubuntu Software Center:**

   - Ubuntu Software Center will run this step automatically after adding the PPA.

   **Synaptic:**

   - Refresh your sources.

   **From the command line (terminal):**

   - Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Now to install Ubuntu-Tweak:

   **Ubuntu Software Center/Synaptic:**

   - Search for **Ubuntu-tweak**, then click install.

   **Command-Line (Terminal):**

   - `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

---

[image: Admins]
*The Admin panel*

---

[image: Tweaks]
*The Tweaks panel*

Comment: why isnt ubuntu tweak not available in official repositories? Is it safe to trust a ppa that it wont have malware code?

Comment: @balki it's a risk, a small one at that, but it is very unlikely for a project like Ubuntu-Tweak to have malware in the PPA. The main reason why Ubuntu-Tweak is not in the repositories, is because it has to be approved - by real people - and they don't always agree with the developer's decisions.

Comment: @balki: That is a very fair concern. But remember PPAs that are ***hosted on Launchpad*** (the ones you add with `add-apt-repository`) *must* contain source code, and also comply with Ubuntu's Code of Conduct. So if you suspect of anything malicious, download the source and inspect it. And for popular projects like Ubuntu Tweak, I bet its source code was scrutinized by many people already. So a PPA is much "safer" than a third party `.deb` binary repository.

Comment: I agree with @MestreLion that it helps to have the source available, and to have a Launchpad build the binaries from that source, so this is much better than a binary repo.  But there is no independent process for reviewing whatever is uploaded by the ppa owners or whoever gets their credentials, and the fact that it is a ppa rather than part of Ubuntu is evidence that the ppa owners haven't managed (or in some cases they haven't tried) to persuade the Ubuntu developers that the package is worthy.  So caution is absolutely advised.  The packages can totally screw up or own your machine.

Comment: In U16.04LTS, doing this yields (at step 2): `W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`...

Comment: ...`E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: ```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak```

Comment: Does NOT work on Ubuntu 20.04 FOCAL

Comment: @RezaTaba Ubuntu-Tweak is no longer maintained, as far as I'm aware. You should be using Gnome-Tweaks if you are on the Gnome Desktop.

Comment: @RolandiXor: Unfortunately Gnome-Tweaks doesn't have Kernel management. I already have it.

Comment: @RezaTaba you can open a new question, if you need to know how to manage your kernels. Quite likely, this has been covered on the site already. Ubuntu Tweak is only *one* solution for this topic.

Answer (score 31):

### For Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus

**Follow this steps:**

1.setup the **GetDeb** Apps repositories - more information on [GetDeb Apps](http://www.getdeb.net):

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

2.Update your sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3.Install Ubuntu tweak tool:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: Does it really work? It reports a depenency error

Comment: This method worked fro Ubuntu Yakkey yak 16:10, thanks!

Comment: Did not work for 18.04. It appears that the key is not available:
    % wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
    gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 11.10 still there isn't a stable version but you can download the alpha version form here https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/next.

You have to add the ppa and install the software, using this terminal command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Source http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Answer (score 8):

To install follow the following steps:

Open the terminal.
Add the required repository with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

Update  the software list with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install Ubuntu Teak with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After that, open dash and type "ubuntu tweak".

Comment: This does NOT work for  Ubuntu Yakkey yak 16.10

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I get:
`The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed Ubuntu Tweaks by downloading the current Debian package for version 0.8.7, for 14.04 trusty, right clicking on it and selecting to open with Ubuntu Software Centre. This is obviously the simplest solution but I found out about it myself by accident. I can find no reference to this method on the internet.

Comment: This is indeed the most simple, but not the most preferable. The reason I've provided the PPA method is because it ensures updates.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I don't have full understanding of ppa. How does one know what kind of software is better installed with ppa?

Comment: I'd rather you take that question to chat, since it would be lot to cover in comments.