# How do I disable the Unity keyboard shortcut overlay?

Tags: keyboard, 12.04, shortcut-keys

Is it possible to disable keyboard shortcut overlay in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: One reason to disable this, or to delay the appearance of the shortcut key overlay, is that it interferes with taking screen captures with the easy screen capture function normally launched by <Super>Button 1. The hints in the overlay appear in the screen capture, which is usually not what you want.

Comment: I'm not using 12.10 but as far as I know this option has not been removed. You can try reseting your compiz/unity settings with `$ compiz.reset`, logout and login then execute `$ dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 12.04 and below:

The *keyboard shortcut overlay* is controlled by an option in the compiz unity plugin.

[image]

In the experimental tab of `ccsm` you can untick the option shown.

Remember the use of CCSM is strongly discouraged - you can achieve the same via `gconf-editor`

[image]

untick the option shown in the path `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay`

Comment: On my fresh 12.10 install, `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell` is not present.

Comment: Why is using `gconf-editor` preferred over using `ccsm` ?

Comment: @KristopherIves - this Q&A will explain your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it

Comment: On my fairly fresh 14.04 installation, /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell is also not present.

Comment: /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell is not present on 16.04.1 either

Answer (score 7):

For those like me that prefer the command line:

### Ubuntu 12.10+:

(Tested up to 16.04)

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false
```

### Ubuntu 12.04 and below:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay --type bool false
```

Comment: Worked nicely on Ubuntu 18.04 running Unity.

Answer (score 5):

## For Ubuntu 12.10:

You can disable this behavior following this steps:

1. [Install **Ubuntu Tweak**](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/62483) [image: Install-It]
2. Open the label *Tweaks* and choice *Unity*

   [image: screenshoot]
3. Now you have to look at the second option called *Shortcuts hints overlay*

   [image: screenshoot2]
4. Now click at the box to turn this feature off, so this remains as this:

   [image: screenshoot3]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would this be done on the command line?

Comment: I have no idea if this is changing some specific option in the *gconf* schema. If so, there should be

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but dconf solution doesn't work any more, at least as of 16.04 (and maybe earlier as well).

For 16.04+, the easiest way is to get Unity Tweak Tool, And go to Overview->Additional, and uncheck "Hold Super for keyboard shortcuts"

Comment: Odd, I just tested [my solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/345182/18665) in 16.04 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

These answers don't work for me at all, and Ubuntu Tweak won't really help, because this is a per-user setting, and by the time you open Ubuntu Tweak, you've already exited this first-time popup (it exits on the first mouse/keyboard event). So what's the point of disabling a popup that's already disabled itself? This setting only makes sense for new users.

I've tried several dconf/gsettings/whatever answers, none could set it successfully. I tried

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/ shortcut-overlay false
```

And also via `/usr/share/compiz/unityshell.xml`, but nope, it won't work. Apparently this popup shows up if the `.config/unity/first_run.stamp` file doesn't exist. So you can:

```
mkdir -p /etc/skel/.config/unity
touch /etc/skel/.config/unity/first_run.stamp
```

This way new users will have this file at first sign-in and won't see the damn popup.