# Stop Keyboard Shortcuts information screen appearing

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, keyboard, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the Unity keyboard shortcut overlay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103352/how-do-i-disable-the-unity-keyboard-shortcut-overlay)

If I hold windows key & click, this keyboard shortcuts screen appears. Is there any way I can stop this appearing altogether?

[image: Keyboard Overlay]

Comment: Per the FAQ, questions about unreleased versions of Ubuntu (12.04) are off-topic. Do you experience this problem with 11.10? If not, please see http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/8724.

Comment: In case someone finds this old thread, the answer below does not work anymore (at least as of 16.04) With newer versions, get Unity Tweak Tool, And go to Overview->Additional, and uncheck "Hold Super for keyboard shortcuts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now this feature to disable isn't in Ubuntu yet.

You can set it by command line for now till the feature is available

```
gconftool --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay" --type bool false
```

In case you get `gconftool` not found, then you can first install the package `gconf2` either from Software center or command line

> sudo apt-get install gconf2

[image: Installing gconftool in USC]

In my case it shows installed as I have already installed it

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! Sorry about the dupe and asking about precise beta.. didn't want to raise it as a bug and waste developer's time!

Comment: Actually I am working on a tool called [Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak) which will be out soon. [It is very easy to use](https://plus.google.com/104684638694714940046/posts/LCrvYWdMGTA)