# How to remove showing the shortcuts?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the Unity keyboard shortcut overlay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103352/how-do-i-disable-the-unity-keyboard-shortcut-overlay)

This is all great stuff.... esential for some. But some of us also need not have to show these shortcuts while pressing a particular key.

Is there a way to do  that? Please note that I am not arguing against how useful all this is. Just would like to know how to unset this option when need it.

thanks

Comment: Which window manager are you using (or rather, which Desktop Environment)?  Are you on Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, or normal Ubuntu?