# How do I disable the keyboard shortcut overlay in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

I'd like to be able to disable the keyboard shortcut overlay that appears when you hold the Super/Meta/Windows key or at least make it hidden. It is annoying, I find no use for it, and it interferes with usage of a Windows VM in VMWare - whenever I click the Meta key, the button is interpreted by both Ubuntu and the VM, causing the overlay to appear.

I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103352/how-do-i-disable-the-unity-keyboard-shortcut-overlay) question describing how to solve the issue in Ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunately, both of the methods provided in there are unavailable in Ubuntu 12.10.

Is there some setting in `gconf` or `dconf` or even `ccsm` that I'm missing, or is this display now unable to be turned off in 12.10?