# Show the shortcuts cheatsheets

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I've just installed trusty with unity.
I press the win key for a while, but the shortcuts cheatsheet won't show up.
I tried with [compiz-settings-manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/103357/26067) and with [ubuntu-tweaks](https://askubuntu.com/a/277655/26067) with no luck at all.

Is there some way to see them? Whay has it changed the way it behaved?

Comment: I assume you are using the default desktop environnment, Unity? This matters; Ubuntu-Gnome, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. Each will have different options...some may not support the cheat sheet screen at all.

Comment: Yeap, using unity

Comment: I don't have this problem but thanks to your post I discovered how to (re)display that shortcuts cheatsheet (`hold the win key for 2+ seconds`), so +1 and thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issue and found the following solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211817

Disabling workspaces brings back the cheatsheet (long pressing the super key). Not sure if you have it enabled though.

Comment: Yeap, I've enabled workspaces, I think it should be considered a bug though.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue only happens when there's more than one workspace. Where can I submmit a bug?

Comment: Same issue here in 14.04. Workspaces are disabled since a very long time. Neither dconf nor ubutu-tweak can re-enable long press in Super to show the shortcuts list overlay. I noticed 2 things: none entries in dconf org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.unityshell have schema, summary, description, type nor default value visible. The entry shortcut-overlay is deleted when set enabled in ubuntu-tweak (even kills dconf window if opened at the moment), and created unticked when disabled. So I closed ubuntu-tweak, relaunched dconf and ticked, close dconf, but still doesn't work even after logoff/in.

Comment: Still not fixed in 16.04