# How can I disable the Super button so that it won't bring up the Search window?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vmware, search

I know this question may have been asked before but the solutions are all out of date or don't work.

I am running Ubuntu as a VM in VMWare on a Mac. If I try to switch from Ubuntu (in VMWare) to the host computer's OS (Mac OS X) but pressing command-tab, it almost always brings up the search box as I switch since the "command" button is the "super" key. When I command-tab back to Ubuntu the search box is now up cover my app and I have to manually click the window I was working on to get back to it. This is very frustrating and makes switching from Ubuntu to a Mac OS X app very difficult.

I've tried using Compiz Config Settings Manager. I've tried changing the keyboard settings. I've tried a variety of command line fixes, but NOTHING seems to disable the super key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the Unity keyboard shortcut overlay?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103352/how-do-i-disable-the-unity-keyboard-shortcut-overlay)

Answer (score 5):

I finally found something that worked:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '""'
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that post Ubuntu 17, this won't work because of the switch to Gnome as the UI shell. The new approach (which worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04) is `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use previous advice in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS:

`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '""'`

It works! But it gives some bad behaviour: i cann't type a "space" symbol, unexpected resets to login screen with disabled keyboard.

Comment: Look here to find a correct answer fo Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Noted and original question duplicated...  Your answer will be deleted automatically in a few days time...

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else using VMware:

1. Go to "Virtual Machine" -> "Settings" -> "Keyboard & mouse" -> "Edit Profile..." for "Mac Profile" -> "Mac Host Shortcuts" -> Check "Enable Mac OS Host Keyboard Shortcuts"

[image: Picture of the menu screen]

Tested using VMWare v7.1.3 and Ubuntu 14.04