# Minimize and Show Applications

Tags: unity, window-management

How can I minimize all the apps in Unity going to desktop and Show all the apps open, just like the top corner compiz function or MacOSx? thanks

Comment: looking `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`D`?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will hide the windows and show the desktop.

For having a look at all opened windows, you might want to use "Scale" compiz plugin, which should be assigned to Shift+Alt+Up.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>

This starts the Compiz Scale filter in Window Picker mode.

If you install CompizConfig Settings Manager (warning - it can really hurt if you stray into other settings), you can view the Scale plugin and change the defaults (including setting hot zones, like top-right).

Answer (score 1):

You can try Ubuntu tweak to set up the hot corner effects.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

After installing it, open Ubuntu-Tweak and go to *Tweak* tab and click on *Compiz Settings*.

[image]

Under *Workspace edge settings*, you can choose the edge where you want to have the hot corner. Select 'Show desktop' from the dropdown list and you will then be able to see the desktop if you move your mouse over the specified corner. Alternatively, choosing 'Show Applications' will enable you to see all the applications that are currently open.

[image]