# What's the name of an application similiar to gnome-tweak tool?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu and can't remember the name of an application that was really useful.

I remember it had a green icon and it appeared on the dash when I searched for "gnome tweak" or something similar.

It was really great for configuring what each corner of the screen would trigger. i.e. show all applications, show desktop, etc..

Anyone knows the name of that app? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Ubuntu Tweak Tool.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)