# How large can Nautilus's thumbnail cache grow?

Tags: nautilus, disk-usage, thumbnails, maintenance

Nautilus's thumbnail cache in `~/.thumbnails` has grown to several hundred megabytes.

Do I need to be concerned about unrestricted growth of this in the long term, or is its size automatically managed somehow?

Comment: If you want more space delete it,
if you want more speed dont delete it :)

Comment: @tachyons When?

Comment: While using nautilus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thumbnail cache is limited to 512MB, so several hundred megabytes sounds logical. It also shouldn't keep files older then 180 days.

If you want to change it, try `gconf-editor`, `/desktop/gnome/thumbnail_cache`.

[image: Image showing maximum_size and maximum_age options for thumbnail_cache]

Exactly the same solution is aplicable to 12.04. You may need to install `gconf-editor`, other then that, nothing has changed.

**Update**

For 14.04 you need to install `dconf-tools`, and launch `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Thanks .can i manually change 180 days to 30 day?

Comment: See the edit above. :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever can you add the info I have about how "it will not cache files above a certain size limit"? If you do then I can delete my answer, which has no up/down votes and is thus useless.

Comment: It has one now. :~) I think your answer should stay, as it also provides a good alternative of using Ubuntu Tweak. A lot of people will have it installed before they even hear about gconf-editor.

Answer (score 2):

It's size is automatically managed, because it has a built in limit of 512MB by default, and deletes thumbnails older than 180days. It will not cache files above a certain size limit either:

[image]

If you want to manage its settings, you can use Ubuntu-Tweak (See how to install it here: [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in an above answer, for 14.04 dconf editor from dconf-tools should be used.
However, I only found the key under

```
org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache
```