# Will CCSM work better with 12.04?

Tags: unity, compiz, 12.04

in my ubuntu 11.10, compiz completely knackered my setup and I was wondering wil this still be a problem with all the unity plugins in 12.04?

Comment: I suggest you create a new user, log in to that user & get a feel for what ccsm is about. Otherwise come over to Ubuntu Forums & you'll get positive info about ccsm, it;s use, ect,

Answer (score 11):

### No, CCSM can still wreck your desktop configuration

MyUnity is the commonly recommended "power user" configuration tool as of 12.04. [Instructions on its use can be found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/101415#101415).

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: It's almost impossible to "WRECK" your login, got anything current to support that?

Comment: @doug: I just found that toggling "Snap windows back to original size" in Grid plugin reliably causes Unity to segfault immediately and on startup. So, yes.

Comment: @  Nicholas That's an issue with the grid plugin not ccsm. If you were to do the same thing thru gconf-editor you'll get the same result. People need to stop blaming ccsm for all the poor behavior of some plugins & in many cases poor behavior adjusting other plugins while the unity plugin is enabled. (not the case with the grid deal you just mentioned but in many cases just disable unity, make your changes, then re-enable the unity plugin. I think I may attach a vid to Mr. Castro's bug on not allowing unity plugin to be disabled at all to show why allowing & doing so sometimes is a good idea

Answer (score 3):

## **Don't expect crashless ccsm in 12.04 unity** ,

<strike>Use it if is necessory</strike> ,If you are ready to any fix any ccsm crash(for advanced users only)

As the alternative you can use

1.[**myunity**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/myunity/)

2.[**Ubuntu tweak**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

**Links**

[What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

[How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/101415#101415)