# ccsm falls ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Hi I find ccsm keeps crashing in ubuntu 12.04
has any-one can suggest to me how can I prevent from this happening
the window opens up and ask to report and I do however it keeps
occurring at least 2-3 time a day 
Any-one can he

Comment: No much more to say on this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/125328/will-ccsm-work-better-with-12-04.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are having issues with CCSM itself and not Compiz. In that case, it would be preferable to instead [file a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) describing the crashes you are getting so developers can work on a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Don't play with ccsm in unity

Yeah, ccsm is still not stable in Unity. If it wrecked your desktop try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch the terminal and type `unity --reset`.

If that doesn't work try
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter console mode. Enter your username and password, and type

```
unity --reset
```

Consider removing ccsm if you want a stable desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Get into a terminal and run:

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: Of course IZX assume that when we accessing to menu, we don't have a shortcut to the terminal window.

Comment: Tried that and it still keeps happening

Comment: @Subv3rsion: your comment makes no sense, but I rolled back the edit since you seem to have taken offense.