# How to replace the Ubuntu Font with other fonts for general text display?

Tags: 12.04, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

How to replace the Ubuntu font with the Windows ClearType font, Mac OS X font or other fonts for general text display (given that you have the neccesary files)?

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X font...you have to download it at http://gnome-look.org/. As for other default fonts, you can find them in Appearances > Font.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu Tweak by referring [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak).

Then you can change it by accessing the Font menu as here

[image]

hope this helps.