# How do I get vlc in the context menu in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, vlc

When right-clicking on a directory once I got an entry "open with vlc". Now with precise this entry is gone. How can I get it back?

edit: Yes I have it in the submenu "open with". But how can I get it in the top menu?

Comment: It is my understanding that once you have installed VLC, it is automatically added as an option in the "open with" of context menu.
Try selecting Properties from the context menu, and in the Open With tab, select VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Ubuntu-tweak

1. First install Ubuntu-tweak

   - [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)
2. Then open it by typing "Ubuntu-tweak" on the dash

   [image: Opening ubuntu tweak from dash]
3. After opening Ubuntu-tweak, go to the **Admin** tab

   [image: Select Admin]
4. Then Go to the **File type manager** option

   [image: file type manager]
5. In this section, do these:

   1. Select a catagory of media types, such *Audio* or *Video*
   2. Select a type of the file, such as *mp3*, *mkv* etc
   3. Double click the currently associated application such as Totem or something
   4. In the new opened small window, Select **VLC media player** and close it.

      [image: changing default apps]
6. Then close the Ubuntu-tweak and see the changes by doing a Right-Click.

**Instruction for Directory:** After subsequent comment by the OP, I realized that, he wanted to enable an entry in the directory with "Open with VLC media player". *(And OP done this, before I edit the answer. ;P)*.

To do so, Follow the steps from 1-5. In the step 5, the procedures are slightly changed. These are:

1. Select the catagory **All**
2. Select the file type **Folder**
3. Double Click it to bring a new window. In this window, do these:

   1. Remove all entries **except Files** from there by selecting one and then pressing **Remove** button.
   2. After removing all except *Files* entries, Press **Add** button and Select the **VLC media player** from the new window and pressing *Add* button there. **Remember to select the Files entry as default** before closing this window.

      The final file type choosing window should look like this

      [image: Files and VLC only]

      *Note that, in the image, Files entry is selected to be the default.*
   3. Close all windows and close the Ubuntu tweak.

That's it.

**If you ever wanted to revert the change,** open Ubuntu-tweak and select the changed file type and Press the **Reset** button at the bottom-right position of Ubuntu tweak. All settings will be restored as before.

Comment: Going to "All" choosing "directory" and deleting all options not being "files" or "vlc" di the job, thanks.
The directory is the only thing one can not change within nautilus. For all other types - I would do it without ubuntu tweak and with nautilus.

Comment: How did you change the ubuntu logo?

Comment: @Aleksandar Oh I see, It is Edubuntu with Unity. Edubuntu has a different logo. See [here in edubuntu website](http://edubuntu.org/)

Comment: @ Aleksander you could see the icon files at '/usr/share/unity/6'. Backup this folder and make changes as you wish. But remember it will be reset after every update! (so save a backup of your changes too)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 13.10 I just created a little script in the nautilus scripts folder and made it executable.

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
vlc -f file://pwd/$1`