# Can I automatically purge every package I've ever uninstalled?

Tags: apt, purge

As an Ubuntu noob, I install and uninstall a lot of packages, to try them out. However, for months, I made the mistake of using `apt-get remove` instead of `apt-get purge`, which I didn't even realize exists.

Is there a way to cause `apt-get` to purge every package I've uninstalled? My system is full of leftover files I neither want or need from dozens of different packages.

Comment: It's not a "mistake" to do this. The difference between _remove_ and _purge_ is that the latter deletes configuration files at the **system** level. Your user configuration files are not affected by either method. As very few programs use system-level configurations, for most programs the two commands would in practice be identical. Further, any configuration files take very little space, and so there is in fact nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: @PaddyLandau: Since many of these packages were services and did in fact have system configuration, I had a _lot_ of files left. It was a mistake in this case, because I had thought `remove` does remove these configuration files.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A simpler alternative, using `aptitude` (not installed by default)

```
sudo aptitude purge '~c'
```

`~c` is an aptitude search pattern, it means 'Select packages that were removed but not purged'. (The single quotes are to prevent the possible expansion of `~c` by the shell as the home directory of a user `c`.)

Note that purging will remove system configuration files, usually located in `/etc`, but personal configuration files, usually in some hidden directory in your home, are not removed (it is not always simple to know which they are).

Comment: What does `~c` mean here?

Comment: @configurator: it is an `aptitude`'s search pattern, it means 'Select packages that were removed but not purged', see [`aptitude` documentation](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `\~c` might be considered preferable, as it will work even if there is a user called `c` (in which case `~c` would be expanded by the shell to `/home/c` or whatever else is `c`'s home directory, before being passed to `aptitude`).

Comment: `~c` is also a valid search expression within `aptitude`'s terminal UI, so you can also use that.

Answer (score 15):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto says:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
```

Comment: if you have uninstalled OpenJDK JRE it's really useless

Comment: This should also work `dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' |xargs sudo dpkg --purge`

Answer (score 3):

those two will clean your packages, but you should get in the habit of using this,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <package name>
```

that will purge the packages.

also check this out, this an utility called ubuntu-tweak, it has a feature that is called janitor, that lets you see the packages to clean, and even the configs. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/112974/how-to-customize-ubuntu-with-ubuntu-tweak/

Comment: `autoclean` and `autoremove` have nothing to do to wath OP asked

Comment: does this edit answer it now?

Comment: Removed the -1, but it doesn't answer, because the OP already know how to do for the future, it ask for already installed packages.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Ubuntu Tweak. It's what I use to clean my systems and it provides a nice GUI for selecting exactly what I want cleaned and what I want to keep.

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu-Tweak to do this job.

1. Install Ubuntu tweak

   - [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)
2. Open it by typing "Ubuntu-tweak" in the dash. To open dash, press **Super** key.

   [image: Ubuntu tweak in dash]
3. Go to the janitor tab, Click on the *Package Configs* in the left bar, then put a Tick mark at the right section of window and then click the **Clean** button. This will ask administrative password, give it and wait for a while....... Your system is clean from old configs.

   [image: cleaning in ubuntu tweak]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, you can remove any leftover configuration files by using the [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) utility ([click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bleachbit)).