# Switching from an Ubuntu derivative to original Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation

I installed Zorin 6 (based on Ubuntu 12.04), because I like all the whistles it has (plymouth screen,compiz effects,installed codecs, sound themes, etc.).
I miss though the modern and futuristic unity environment (launcher, dash, HUD, indicators etc.).

1. Is there a way to switch from Zorin to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and keep all these effects?
   Or
2. What additional software should I install in an Ubuntu clean install to add the effects Zorin has (plymouth, compiz effects, sounds, audio and video codecs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to install Ubuntu on another partition.

Then install the software included in Zorin in Ubuntu. You can install these

1. Compiz config settings manager with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
2. All necessary codecs, MS fonts and flash by using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
3. Install Ubuntu-tweak : [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

After installing necessary software, copy the configuration folders from the old Zorin partiton to your Ubuntu home. The folders are `.config`, `.gconf` and `.compiz-1` and if you want `.local` (this may not be needed).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just revert to Ubuntu.

However, you can install additional software in Ubuntu which can make your experience somewhat the same.

- `plymouth` is already installed in Ubuntu 12.04.
- Compiz effects can be achieved by installing `compizconfig-settings-manager`.
- Audio and video codecs can be installed by installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.