# I screwed up my icons with MyUnity

Tags: unity, icons, myunity

I wanted MyUnity specifically for the ability to have more than 4 virtual desktops, that is really all that I absolutely needed it for.  However, then I got to playing with it wanting to customize my themes and whatnot, all was going ok until all my system icons went missing.

That is to say, they're not *completely* missing, but all folders *and* files without a live preview show up as a page with a bent-corner. Also, folder icons in the alt-tab popup show up as completely transparent; they still take up room and have a label, just no visible icon.  I have tried playing around with myunity themes and icon sets and no matter what I can't seem to get things back to where they were.

This isn't a huge encumbrance but it is starting to get more and more annoying and I feel like I'm missing out in understanding something about how Unity works.

What could have caused this and how do I fix it?

**Update**: Per a commenter's suggestion I tried running `unity --reset-icons`. After 15 minutes it was still scrolling by (I assume it was in a loop). [Here is what was in my terminal buffer at the time I ctrl+c'ed.](http://pastebin.com/Gfrf2b8Y)

Comment: thy this `unity-reset-icons`

Comment: @blade19899 - see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Unity lists some more icon themes other than the installed ones, It displays the cursor themes as icon themes also. I suspect you applied some invalid icon theme. Change the icon theme to "Humanity icon theme", it will reset the theme to default.

I suggest using Ubuntu-tweak to change the icon theme, because it doesn't have that behaviour.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Comment: Yeah, I really wish it was just back to the way it was with 6 desktops. That's all that I ever really wanted.

Comment: After setting the icon, you may want to reset the unity desktop configuration too. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/17610/61218)

Comment: ah great, Humanity was what I was looking for - do you know what was the default theme by any chance?

Comment: The default Icon theme is "ubuntu-mono-dark" with the gtk theme "Ambiance".

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, found a way to fix it:
"System Settings"->"Appearance"-> Switch Theme.

It restored my icons.

Cheers!