# Eclipse colour scheme is terrible in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, colors

I have modified my eclipse colour theme to my liking but just cant seem to develop in peace because I keep having to squint and stare at the screen for certain elements. The colour default scheme is simply pathetic!

I have no idea what these elements are called and hence instead of attempting to describe them I have attached screenshots. How can I modify these elements to make them more humanly readable?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1, for `humanly readable`, As We are human being and also "Ubuntu for human being" I hope this will soon be fixed. :)

Comment: Thanks [Sergey](http://askubuntu.com/users/14564/sergey) for the edit as well! =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That color is controlled by your gtk theme, which is "Ambiance" by default in Ubuntu.

As a quick workaround to this problem, you can try changing the color to a darker one. To do this, open a terminal and use the below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme "bg_color:#D7D7D7;"
```

The color value is a darker one than the default. You can use your own color value. To generate hex value of color, you can use [agave [image: Install agave]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/agave).

Also, you may want to change the theme to a darker one. I personally like the "greybird" theme included in the Lubuntu. You can install the theme by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes
```

or using this link [shimmer-themes [image: Install shimmer-themes]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shimmer-themes)

After installation, change the theme using Ubuntu-tweak:

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Hope this will make eclipse *humanly readable* again. :)