# How to display Trash and Home folder icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons

I've googled quite a bit but nothing I've found works. I just want to display the Trash, Home folder, Computer etc icons on my Desktop in Ubuntu.

The closest I've come is installing `dconf-tools`, running it, going to `org -> gnome -> desktop -> background` and checking `show-desktop-icons` then `org -> gnome -> nautilus -> desktop` and checking the icons I want to show.

Nothing happens.

I've also tried looking in `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `gconf-editor` but can't find anything there.

Ideas?

Comment: For me, it was in System settings => Desktop, there are some desktop icon switchers :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can enable them using [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/):

[image: Unsettings "Desktop" tab]

Or you can use the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop computer-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop network-icon-visible true
```

Comment: Perfect. I couldn't find Unsettings (well, `sudo apt-get install unsettings` didn't work) but the command line commands did work. I gotta ask - those commands look remarkably similar to the changes I made using `dconf-tools` (the paths are identical) - how come it didn't work from there? Thanks again

Answer (score 10):

**Story behind**

I don't have any of those icons in my desktop, so I just checked the options that you mentioned and this were already activated!

So, maybe there is a problem with `dconf`, well I don't know, but these configurations doesn't make any change in my system (Ubuntu 12.10).

**The answer**

1. [Install **Ubuntu Tweak**](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/62483) [image: Install-It]
2. Click in the *Tweaks* label and then in the *Desktop Icons* icon (sounds recursive :) )

   [image: SS_1]
3. Finally you should see a window *similar* than the following allowing you to show/hide the icons.

   [image: SS_2]

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZZl2.png) is my result. It works even when `donf` have different values.

Answer (score 0):

On Lubuntu, you can enable or disable the Trash and Home folder desktop icons by running `xfdesktop-settings` and clicking on the "Icons" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Tweaks with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Then, open Tweaks and go to the desktop tab and uncheck whatever you do not want on your desktop.

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]

Answer (score 0):

If using `nautilus` (default file manager in Ubuntu) OR `nemo` (a much better file manager in my opinion), see my answer here for info on how to do it for both cases: [How to set Nemo as the default file manager in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu-18-04/1173861#1173861).

In short, for `nemo` use `dconf-editor` and for `nautilus` use `gnome-tweak-tool`. Again, refer to the link above for screenshots and details.