# Impossible to see files in Trash via Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, trash

I saw some posts here teaching how to lead with it problem but any of them helped me.
My problem is i deleted the Trash icon from my Desktop, and after that, i noticed few days after that accessing the Trash via Nautilus in my Ubuntu 12.04 does not show any file even it have files in it, where i can see through `~/.local/share/Trash`.
So, how i can solve the problem of seeing my files at Trasg through Nautilus and restore the desktop icon of it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files in the Trash, you could find it in `~/.local/share/Trash/files/`. Just copy the files in your desired location.

For your other issue of showing the Trash icon on Desktop. [See this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267049/how-to-display-trash-and-home-folder-icons/267059#267059)

Hope this would be helpful.