# How do I remove home folder from the desktop?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I don't know how I changed this, after a restart I found this home folder on the desktop. I don't want it there - how do I remove it? Left click does not show an option to delete it.

Here's a screenshot: [image]

Comment: check with nautilus the directory structure of /home/, /home/$USER/ and /home/$USER/Desktop. Have you got Ubuntu Tweak installed? UT has an option to show "home". See http://askubuntu.com/a/267056/15811

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has changed under Ubuntu 19.04 "Disco Dingo":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```

Similarly for the Trash icon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

Should you wish the icons back again, repeat the command with `false` changed to `true`.

Comment: how did you know where to find this command?

Comment: No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons”

Comment: @Soerendip - because that was for 19.04. See [For Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479546/how-do-i-remove-home-folder-from-the-desktop/1407178#1407178) answer.

Answer (score 27):

**For Ubuntu 22.04 or later:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false
```

Comment: Odd. Even after a restart, this did not work for me (v22.04.3), but the settings UI did https://askubuntu.com/a/1410890/849369

Answer (score 13):

#### For Ubuntu versions prior to 19.04:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible false
```

#### For Ubuntu 19.04 or later, [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133526/186134).

Comment: Similarly, to hide the trash icon, do `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false`

Comment: for Mate Desktop (fork of Gnome2), use `gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop home-icon-visible false`

Answer (score 10):

On ubuntu 22.04
Setting -> Appearance -> Desktop Icons -> Show Personal folder -> disable it
[image]