# Hide trash icon in Nautilus (not on desktop)

Tags: nautilus, trash

By default, Nautilus show the icon of the trash, in the side panel. I wish to keep the function of the trash but hide the icon in Nautilus in the side panel. I'm not talk about to hide the trash icon on desktop (different topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Trash and Home folder icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267049/how-to-display-trash-and-home-folder-icons)

Comment: No, your link talk about icon on desktop. My topic is about icon in Nautilus.