# Not able to change launcher icon size

Tags: unity

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 Iam new to ubuntu OS and facing little issues in using the same.
My problem,
1. not able to change the font size of launcher, tried this below
System Settings --> Appearence --> could not find change launcher icon size

1. How to have a start button like in windows xp or something like in earlier ubuntu which  had options like 
         Application
         Places 
         System
   easier to access than the launcher

-Thanks & regards,
Manju

Comment: echo $DESKTOP_SESSION displays ubuntu-2d, after this i tried moving back to unity by, logging out and clicking on ubuntu icon of user name to unit, still no luck

Comment: hello @Manju there should be change launcher icon size in the bottom... Are you sure there is nothing related to launcher in appearence ?

Comment: Hi, Iam sure that there is no option to change the icon size of launcher in System Settings-->Appearance

Answer (score 2):

You can resize the launcher in Unity 2D, in Ubuntu 12.04, by manually editing a few files. [This link contains detailed instructions.](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/resize-unity-2d-launcher-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

On later versions, you'll find a setting already in [the 'Appearance' configuration window.](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/daily-ubuntu-tips-resize-ubuntu-unity-launcher/)

Comment: which is better, unity or unity2D ? i will also start looking @ above link you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Just [install ubuntu tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) and go to "tweaks"->"unity". There will be options to configure the dash, launcher and some couple more things including a way to change the launcher icon size.

[image]