# How to install Google Earth on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, google-earth

I love the Google Earth program in windows, but what does it take to get it to run in Linux and on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 24):

To install Google Earth, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32bit:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
```

For 64bit:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Once the download is done, just run the 2 commands below:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Once installed, you can run it multiple ways:

1. Launch the software from the Dash.
2. Press Alt and F2 and type google-earth.
3. Open a terminal and type google-earth &.

Comment: For 64-bit 13.04 as of 28 Sep 2013, the Google Earth package seems to no longer install properly.

Comment: @Susan then you need to file a bug with Google about that.

Comment: I found that I needed to install the package 'lsb-core' before I could get the above to work. By preceeding the `dpkg` command with `aptitude install lsb-core` I got the install to work smoothly.

Comment: Doesn't `apt-get -f` handles installing dependencies automatically?

Comment: @MestreLion yes it does - that is the whole point of that line, to install any packages listed as missing dependencies from the `dpkg` step.

Comment: What's the command to run it?

Comment: @Zaz see addition in the answer.

Comment: @Mitch: Thank you.  Turns out for me, it's `google-earth-pro`

Comment: Still the real solution for Debian in 2019 and likely Ubuntu and Mint and probably MX Linux

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the "easy" (and also the "official") way:

- Visit the [Google Earth Pro Website](https://www.google.com/earth/desktop/), now called *"Google Earth Pro (GEP) for Desktop"*

  - *("regular" [Google Earth](https://www.google.com/earth/) now runs directly on Google's [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) Browser)*
- Follow the instructions until you reach the [Download and Agreement page](https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html)
- Download and open the `.deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)` that matches your architecture, either 32 or 64 bits. If not sure, or *if you're using Ubuntu 13.10 onwards*, choose the 32-bit one.
- It will open in Ubuntu Software Center. Click `Install`. Done :)

This is also a simpler version of the method recommended by [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki on GoogleEarth](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth). (simpler because `lsb_core`, as all other dependencies, are automatically installed by Software Center)

Comment: As of 2018-11-17 the GE website says Chrome is required, but clicking on "pro" option takes one to the above linked download page and doesn't appear to need Chrome (I have it installed but it's not used whilst GE is running).

Comment: Thanks @pbhj ! I've edited my answer to reflect this new information

Answer (score 2):

Just install [Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) and under the apps tab, you will find a link to install Google Earth directly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also PPA for Google Earth, but for some reason there is no `google-earth-stable`, but `google-earth-ec` package. The `ec` is *Enterprise Client*. The difference is that it will ask (once) to which server to login, defaulting to public google server. And the icon is ugly yellow.

1. Import google signing key

> wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

2. Add Google Earth PPA

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

3. Update

> sudo apt update

4. Install

> sudo apt install google-earth-ec-stable

Comment: typo:  google-earth-stable not google-earch-stable.  Thanks.