# Make <super>+1 shortcut to open a new window

Tags: 13.04, shortcuts

I use Ubuntu 13.04 freshly installed.

I like to use the shortcut  <kbd>super</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd> (until 9) to open applications.

**Problem is** : When I hit it a second time, it shows me the window I previously opened, instead of opening a new window, as I would like it to do. How can I change that ?
I tried in Settings, and with about:config, Nothing!!

I also would like to change shortcuts <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> with <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, but I didn't find where I can. I found for <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> in Settings, but not for left and right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) where you can do lot of tweaks.

Install the item from software center. Please follow [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) to install it from the software center.

Good luck with tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this option is not available in this software.