# Some Nice Icon Themes for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, icon-themes

Last night I was searching for some good looking icon themes availabe for Ubuntu, but unfortunately could not find any post which gives a list of themes :(. From yesterday night I started searching icons themes and installing one by one.

So thought to share some of them hope it will help others to get a bunch of them in one post. This is a [Q&A-Style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) tutorial which will cover:

- Few good icon themes which are used in famous Ubuntu type distros and are available in repository.
- Look and feel through pictures.
- How to easily install?

I also request others to share their experiences of some awesome icon themes.

Once themes are installed [Ubuntu-Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) will help to change and manage them, since I could not find another way to change the themes in Unity. In xfce(Xubuntu) it can be changed from **Appearance**.

<sub>**Just believe me this post will not be vast. If I'll remove pictures then it will become small, but it will not look good. Please give suggestion to make it small.**</sub>

Comment: This isn't a real question - could end up hundreds of answers long - is completely subjective. There are already more than enough places on the web with themes.

Comment: @Elfy: I just wanted to share few of them which is quite popular and are used in some famous desktop environment. Believe me you'd also like some of them. I also request you to share some of them in this post. I don't know what is wrong in this question.

Comment: I understand what you wanted to do - I just think that blogs are the best place for this sort of thing, not a Q&A site. As I said it's completely subjective. I'm not worried enough to get into protracted discussions about it.

Comment: @Elfy: Then what will you say about: [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) post?

Comment: Common please, read the header: *This question exists as it fills a specific criterion. While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and **will likely be closed** per the FAQ.*

Comment: @Braiam: I assure you that this post will not be big.I just wanted to create a post which tell about some good Icon Themes at one place. If I'll expand then really it going to be more posts. :(

Comment: Instead of "good" (which is subjective) do a question about "how do I install X icon theme?" or even better "how do I install icon themes?" which aren't too broad and could attract very good answers.

Comment: I really spent a lot of time to make this post. I'm new here and of course not much experienced like others. My motto was only to help other. I got good appreciation, support and suggestions for my post. I'll say thank you to all.

Comment: @SauravKumar - pop into the general chatroom if you wish to discuss further.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Everything is clear now from the events and comments here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Gnome Colors

GNOME-Colors is a set of GNOME icon themes, with some inspiration from
Tango, Elementary, Discovery, Tango Generator and others.

Its goal is to create an easy way for anyone to make their desktop
consistently match their **moods**, **wallpapers**, **laptop colors**, etc.

The reason why I categorized all gnome icon themes in here is that they use same symbols and icons for all. But they change in color and feel.

1. **Brave**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme brave` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-brave-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: brave]
2. **Dust**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme dust` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-dust-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: dust]
3. **Human**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme human` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-human-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: human]
4. **Illustrious**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme illustrios` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-illustrious-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: illustrious]
5. **Noble**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme noble` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-noble-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: noble]
6. **Wine**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme wine` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-wine-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: wine]
7. **Wise**

   - To install search as `gnome icon theme wise` in `Synaptic Package Manager` or execute following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install gnome-wise-icon-themes
     ```

   Snapshot:

   [image: wise]

**To install all of them at once execute this command:**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-brave-icon-theme gnome-colors gnome-colors-common gnome-dust-icon-theme gnome-human-icon-theme gnome-illustrious-icon-theme gnome-noble-icon-theme gnome-wine-icon-theme gnome-wise-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 1):

## NuoveXT2

It is the default icon theme for LXDE, also known as nuoveXT2 icon theme.

- To install **NuoveXT** search `nuovext`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed package or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lxde-icon-theme
  ```

  Snaptshot:

  [image: nuovext2]

Answer (score 0):

## Gartoon Redux

Gartoon Redux is an expanded version of the Gartoon theme, with dozens of new icons. PNG renderings of the SVG icons are also provided. It like it because of cartoon look :P

- To install **Gartoon Redux** search `gartoon redux`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed package or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux
  ```

  Snaptshot Overview:

  [image: gartoon]

  Snaptshot some icons:

  [image: gartoonicons]

Answer (score 0):

## Gperfection2

- To install **gperfection2** search `gperfection2`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install two listed packages or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-gperfection2 gtk-clearlooks-gperfection2-theme
  ```

  Snaptshot:

  [image: gperfection2]

Answer (score 0):

## Human

- To install **Human** search `Human icon theme`   in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install human-icon-theme
  ```

  Snapshot:

  [image: human]

Answer (score 0):

## Humility

- To install **Humility** search `gnome humility icon theme`   in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-humility-icon-theme
  ```

  Snapshot:

  [image: humility]

Answer (score 0):

## Humanity

**Humanity** and **Humanity Dark** are nice and well polished icon themes for the GNOME desktop. **They are installed by-default in Ubuntu** althogh if missing accidently:

- To install **Humanity** search `Humanity` in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install humanity-icon-theme ubuntu-mono
  ```

  Snapshot Humanity:

  [image: humanity]

  Snapshot Monodark:

  [image: monodark]

Answer (score 0):

## Breathe

The Breathe icon theme is a refresh of the Human icon theme using KDE's Oxygen icon set as an inspiration but with that distinctly Human feel. The Breathe Icon Set is created and maintained by the Breathe Icon Team and Ubuntu Artwork community.

It is one of my favorites :)

- To install **Breathe** search `breathe icon theme`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed package or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install breathe-icon-theme
  ```

  Snaptshot:

  [image: breathe]

Answer (score 0):

## Oxygen

Oxygen is the standard icon theme for KDE 4, but follows the freedesktop.org
icon schemes, so it can be used in other desktop environments using this
specification.

- To install **Oxygen** search `oxygen icon theme`   in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install first two packages. or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete
  ```

  Snapshot:

  [image: oxygen]

Answer (score 0):

## Yasis

Yasis is Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) icon set for GNOME Desktop.

- To install **Yasis** search `gnome icon theme yasis`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed package or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-yasis
  ```

  Snaptshot:

  [image: yasis]

Answer (score 0):

## Gilouche

This theme is the default one used in openSUSE. The icon theme was previously known as openSUSE Industrial, but has been
renamed to Gilouche as well.

- To install **Gilouche** search `gilouche`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install the listed package or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-theme-gilouche
  ```

  Snaptshot:

  [image: gilouche]

Answer (score 0):

## Dropline Nuovo and Dropline Neu

- To install **Dropline Nuovo** and **Dropline Neu** search `gnome dropline`  in `Synaptic Package Manager` and install two listed packages or execute following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-nuovo gnome-themes-extra
  ```

  Snaptshot Nuovo:

  [image: nuovo]

  Snapshot Neu:

  [image: neu]