# Chromium can't clear browsing data

Tags: 13.10, chromium

When I attempt to "Clear browsing data" in chromium I see the following in a terminal.

```
 [...] RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 RemoveFilesRecursively: unlink dir: Directory not empty
 [3640:3669:0206/181710:ERROR:plugin_data_remover_impl.cc(263)]
 ClearSiteData returned error
```

How can I tell which directory it is having problems with?

This is using

```
Chromium 32.0.1700.102 Ubuntu 13.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Chromium seems to use the following directories:

```
~/.config/chromium
~/.cache/chromium
```

<sup>Where `~` represents the home directory in `/home` 
 The `.` before the files mean they are hidden, so you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view them in file browser.</sup>

You can remove files with [`ubuntu-tweak`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)'s Janitor feature, or with [BleachBit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/):
[image]

or simply by running:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
```

And if you want to be sure it has been removed, you can use [`srm`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/secure-delete/):

```
srm -rf ~/.config/chromium
srm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
```

Which overwrites the files etc, and may give more effective information if rhe folders cannot be deleted.

For all of the above, make sure `chromium` is not running.

Comment: I did rm -rf ~/.config/chromium ; rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
 but I still get exactly the same errors.

Comment: Do the files even exist? Look in `.config` & `.cache` in your home directory, and see if they exits - that may be the issue. The files are automatically generated on Chromium being opened.

Comment: ls -lad .config/chromium/
drwx------ 5 marshall marshall 4096 Feb  6 22:25 .config/chromium/  .ls -lad .cache/chromium/
drwx------ 3 marshall marshall 4096 Feb  6 22:25 .cache/chromium/

Comment: Weird.. Try using `srm` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ubuntu tweak's janitor.

[image]