# dpkg: error processing package linux-image

Tags: bug-reporting

I've recently had a Windows 7 malfunction and decided to give Ubuntu a try. I noticed that 14.04 had been released and decided to grab it. It's been working fine up until yesterday. For some reason, it's having difficulty downloading anything or updating or upgrading when I put in "sudo apt-get update" or "sudo apt-get upgrade".

The error I'm coming across is:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is only a piece of the code, but it's been identified as a bug, but I'm not sure how to fix it or how to amend it.

I'm not having problems functionality wise, it's just annoying to not be able to update or download anything.

Comment: There should be more information before the line "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic (--remove):".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to remove old kernels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419095/unable-to-remove-old-kernels) (In my experience this usually means you have a separate `/boot` partition, which is pretty small and nearly filled up with kernels. If not, [adding the information Braiam requested](http://askubuntu.com/questions/473588/dpkg-error-processing-package-linux-image#comment710008_473588) should make it possible to figure this out. You can [edit] your question with that any any other information you think might be relevant.)

Comment: This question was already answered, and the answer accepted, over 3 months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
grub# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
```

grub.cfg is malformed. "grub#" should just be "#". Edit the file with `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and remove the first 4 characters. After you have done that run `sudo update-grub` and then `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

`grep -rH partner /etc/apt/sources*` shows that you have the partner repository enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list`. It only needs to be enabled once so to fix it do `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list` then `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: How you know this is the problem?

Comment: And? There's nothing in the question that would suggest that this is the problem, unless you are psychokinestic.

Comment: @Braiam There were a lot of comments and a link to the grub.cfg was posted. Some editor came along later and deleted the comments.