# Configuration changes resist to apply, and some other mess; need help!

Tags: 12.04, themes, desktop-environments, volume-control

Can't say exactly what might have done this, *(I was trying `Xephyr` and removed some old kernels in my last good session..)* but now I can see that some mess has been made.

- The themes don't apply properly, here's a snapshot. The dark colours of the panel and the menu bar are not meant to be for my Radiance theme. The Icon themes too resist to change;
  [image: snap1]
- I tried to login with gnome2 environment and all I get is a super zoomed window, the mouse cursor almost than the size of my palm! *(but gnome2 is working fine for another user in the system)*;

> How can I fix these?

---

#### Update 01:

Here's a snap showing `gnome-tweak-tool` and `dconf-editor` window theme is already set to *Radiance* but still...

**Something seems to be wrong with Shell Theme.. Is it?**

[image: advancedSettings]

> (..also I noted Adwaita being default, shouldn't that be Ambiance? ***Isn't Ambience the default for Ubuntu 12.04?***)

#### Update 02:

Despite changing Icon theme to *Moka* and Window theme to *Radiance* the changes don't apply.
[image: uTweak]

Firefox shouldn't appear the way it is now with Radiance..
[image: firefox]

Answer (score 0):

#### RE the themes

You need to set both the GTK theme and the window manager theme to the theme you want to use:

1. [Install Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak).
2. Navigate to this page in Ubuntu Tweak and set both "Gtk theme" and "Window theme" to the one you want to use.

   [image]

Comment: an upgrade is in progress, so I'll try that later.. but I do have `dconf` with me, any ideas with the schema for the same? and yes with `dconf` too I'm unable to change the Icon theme the way I could before..

Comment: @hash: No idea. :P When it's done, though, try running a `dconf watch /` command while changing the value in Ubuntu Tweak. That's a great way to find the dconf entry for settings sometimes.

Comment: ubuntu-tweak doesn't help either.. window theme is already set to Radiance.. updated Q..