# How can I switch between windows with an active corner like in gnome 3?

Tags: unity, mouse

The title basically says it.

I want to switch fastly between windows without using the keyboard. How do I do that in Unity?

"How does Gnome 3 do it?":
Gnome 3 has an active corner in the upper left (That was used by Unity to show the launcher earlier). It shows all windows on one screen, so you can select which you want to focus on.

Comment: How does gnome 3 does it? It would be better to give more info on this issue.

Comment: Done. The description is also true for KDE and Mate.

Comment: Does [ubuntu tweak](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) work in lubuntu? The way I know of enabling that is via ubuntu tweak

Comment: And by the way, that feature is called "Spread Windows" and in unity it can be accessed via `Super + w`. Maybe the same key combinations can work in lubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of Acatar Partos comment:

1. Install ubuntu-tweak, open it.
2. Go to optimizations.
3. Click workspace
4. In the upper left dropdown menu, select show windows.