# How can I clean the boot partion

Tags: boot-partition

This is the statuts of my hardisk , How can I clean  the boot partion to free some space

[image]

Comment: If you have extra kernels you should remove those. With 16.04 or later: `sudo apt autoremove` Other clean issues: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace

Comment: Short term, you can clean out some of your old kernels that aren't used any more... but this will be a repetitious job. There are plenty of questions/answers here on AU that will help you with that. Long term, a better solution would be to resize your sda1 partition. It's too small. Your swap partition is too small also.

Comment: I have increased the swap partition to 12Go and I have tried to increase the boot partition but I could not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your boot partition is also your root partition, so you need to clean up your Ubuntu installation.  What really needs to happen, is your root partition needs to be larger, maybe 30-50 GBytes, but that's not the question, is it?

To clean up your root partition, the easiest way would be to install **BleachBit**, run it in superuser mode, and check what you want cleaned up.

Install **BleachBit** by running:

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Here are a few other things I do from time to time keep my system clean.

**Option 1:**  Run **autoclean** and **autoremove** to get rid of any packages you don't need any more.  I type this in sometimes while installing/removing programs because it's quick and easy.

```
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

**Option 2:**  Open up the **Ubuntu Software Center**, and click the **Installed** tab, and scroll through the list, removing any software packages you no longer need or want.

**Option 3:**  [Install Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) and use it's **Janitor** tab to clean up unwanted data sitting around on your system.  You check the left check-boxes to scan and find data, and then you check the right side to select what you want to delete.  I find that Ubuntu Tweak will still get some things BleachBit doesn't, plus Ubuntu Tweak will remove old Linux Kernels and re-do grub for you.  Just now, Ubuntu Tweak Janitor actually freed up more disk space (~500MBytes) on my system than BleachBit did (~270MBytes), and I ran BleachBit first.

**Ubuntu Tweak** is "obsolete ware", because the developer announced about a year ago (May 2016) that he would no longer be developing it. It has still worked great for me, but you may not want to use it at all, especially as time goes on.  It is the only way I know to completely remove old kernels, as it seems **BleachBit** and **autoremove** don't do the trick yet when it comes to completely removing old kernels, or maybe I just don't know how it is done with those tools.

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak is obsolete and should not be used any more.

Comment: @heynnema - That's a good point.  I added a note at the end to let people know that they may not want to use Ubuntu Tweak because it is no longer being developed.

Comment: Use `Synaptic` to remove old kernels and their baggage. Just type "linux-" into the search box, and then "completely remove" all but the newest two versions.